# How to set XHR breakpoint in Firefox as in Chrome

Tags: firefox, javascript-debugger

I couldn't figure out a way to add filter like "URL contains...." XHR break-point like in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XHR Breakpoints in Firefox developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365484/xhr-breakpoints-in-firefox-developer-tools)

Comment: Hey Dave,  Agree with you, but I asked this question long before the question you have shared. So not sure which one should be considered as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break on XHR feature has been added to Firefox 65. It's available on the right side-pane of the debugger tab:

[image: Firefox 65 nightly]

Currently it's available for download in the nightly build.

Comment: Thank you @Istvan - I will accept this as answer once it is released.

Comment: @PrabhakarKasi Firefox 65 is finally out and contains the above feature, enjoy :)