# XHR Breakpoints in Firefox developer tools

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-developer-tools

Does anybody know how to break on a XHR request on Firefox developer tools?
Earlier in firebug I added breakpoints under Net panel. As the firebug is discontinued any workaround for Firefox developer tools is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's currently (Firefox 57.0) not possible. It's requested in [bug 821610](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821610).

Also other Break on… features like [breaking on DOM mutations](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004678) and [breaking on cookie changes](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=895893) are still missing.

Those features are given [high priority for implementation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806#c20) regarding missing Firebug features.

Answer (score 1):

The break on XHR feature has been added to Firefox 65 (Debugger -> right side pane -> XHR Breakpoints):

[image]

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks Istvan!

Comment: Strange, doesn't show up on mine.  Chrome is able to intercept and breakpoint all XHR for the same website. I was having trouble copying and editing the request on Chrome before it got sent. Thats why I chose firefox... confused